# How to allocate a large structure in a heap baked `Arc<T>` without stack overflow in Rust?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow

I have a large structure.

The size of arrays is known at compile time and I will not use multiple `Vec<_>` for that.

This current initialization code trigger a stack overflow in unoptimized builds:

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct OuterStruct {
    pub big_array_0: [u32; 108],

    pub big_array_1: std::sync::Mutex<[Option<String>; 65536]>,

    pub big_array_2: [AtomicUsize; 65536],
}

fn main() {
    let manager = Arc::new(OuterStruct {
        big_array_0: [0; 108], // Doesn't explode my stack

        big_array_1: std::sync::Mutex::new(std::array::from_fn(|_| None)),

        big_array_2: std::array::from_fn(|_| 0.into()),
    });
}
```

So how do I allocate this structure in it's own `Arc<OuterStruct>` baked heap allocation without triggering a stack overflow ?

I am using latest stable Rust, prefer avoiding unsafe code and I have `#![deny(invalid_value)]` so some `std::mem::MaybeUninit` based solutions will error (these would cause warnings anyway).

Comment: The quick solution is to always compile with release flag

Comment: I don't think there are other way than to use unsafe to be sure to have this optimization.

Comment: I tried increasing my stack size as a temporary workaround but even using `RUSTFLAGS='-C link-args=-Wl,-zstack-size=268435456'` (yes it's a 256MiB stack) during cargo build trigger a stack overflow at runtime. I will try optimized builds later although I prefer avoiding this, unsafe is okay actually but not clean.

Comment: If you can tolerate the indirection, you could fairly easily create `Box<[Option<String>; 65536]>` and `Box<[AtomicUsize; 65536]>` via `Vec::into_boxed_slice` and `<Box<[T]> as TryInto<Box<[T; N]>>>::try_into`.  Indeed you could then even convert those into their own `Arc`s without moving to the stack, though obviously that isn't the same as the whole struct being in a single `Arc`.

Comment: "*unsafe is okay actually but not clean*" - would look something like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15ebcaddab76db107130f70d8d156fa2).

Comment: A slightly cleaner version: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ae7cdcf51fcfec2b0be827ac4859d4e

Comment: @eggyal Is there actually a guarantee that `MaybeUninit::uninit()` will not allocate from the stack here? I'm not sure there is...

Comment: @cdhowie There is not, but it tends to be optimized well (I don't know about debug builds, though). If you want a guarantee, try https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_uninit (nightly only).